# Initialize Members (whose constructors accept arguments) in a struct in a class

Tags: c++, class, struct, initialization

I am receiving errors from my compiler when I try code with this general format:

in classname.hpp

```
#include "otherclass.hpp"
class classname {
public:
    typedef struct {
        otherclass membername(sometype);
    } structname;
    void functionname(structname& exampleData);
}
```

in main.cpp, I define a variable exampleData:

```
classname::structname exampleData;
```

in classname.cpp, I have a function that uses exampleData and attempts to initialize the member, membername, of the struct:

```
void classname::functionname(structname& exampleData){
    sometype a;
    exampleData.membername(a);
}
```

I am receiving an error from my compiler stating:

> Undefined symbols: `classname::structname::membername(sometype)`" referenced from `classname::functionname(classname::structname&)` in classname.o. ld: symbol(s) not found

I think that my error lies within the line

```
otherclass membername(sometype)
```

I also thought it could be:

```
otherclass membername(sometype& a)
```

But I received the same errors.

I'm wondering if this is legal to do, to have a member in a struct in a class whose constructor is not (). In main.cpp, when I declare exampleData, membername has not been initialized yet. Is this legal or am I hunting in the wrong place?

Comment: Your code can't possibly be right, there are tons of semicolons missing. Fix up the code and check again.  Also, your function `functionname` is just a global (free) function in your hpp file, not a member function.

Comment: -1 not posting the real code (e.g. the posted code lacks semicolons). we're not telepaths. i'm voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: -1 for not posting the compiler command that lead to the error. If it's a linker error we should be able to verify that you've linked all the relevant modules together.

Comment: Why are you doing `typedef struct {...} structname;`? It's not C, please learn proper C++. Just write `struct structname{...};`.

Comment: @PawelZubrycki if it compiles in C++ then it _is_ proper C++.

Comment: @John: Nope, it's valid C++, not proper C++.

Answer (score 5):

The error you're getting looks a lot like a linker error caused by the function `classname::structname::membername` not being defined anywhere.  From the code you've posted, it looks like you've just *declared* the function without providing a definition anywhere, meaning that the code will compile but not link.  You should be able to fix this by providing an implementation for the function somewhere in your program.  It doesn't have anything to do with whether the parameter is taken by reference; in both cases you still need to provide an implementation.

Comment: I'm still unclear. What do you mean by providing a definition (aside from the function in the class.cpp file?) or by providing an implementation functionname elsewhere in my program? Thanks

Comment: In your nested struct `structname` inside of `classname`, you've prototyped a function called `membername`.  However, you haven't provided an implementation of that function anywhere, meaning that if you call the function, the linker won't be able to produce a valid program because it can't find the code that's supposed to be executed when the function is called.  Implementing this function will fix this problem.

Comment: This answer is exactly right, as is your compiler: You don't have a definition `classname::structname::membername` (by the way where on Earth did you come up with those monstrous names? Everyone knows that a class is called `Foo` ;-) ). Say `otherclass membername(sometype) { return otherclass; }` or something like that to provide a skeleton definition.